# How to set up a router and connect it to another wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model B to use it as a web dev server for home and school. Actually, when Im at home, the pi connect to my home wifi so I can easily use it with the local ip adress; I have a complete web server installed and   an FTP server. I have 2 problems at the moment :

1. When I turn off the Pi, I can't really know if I can unplug the power wire or not yet. So my question is: Does a web terminal is the solution? I would like to have shell output like I was connected to HDMI to know when the Pi is really off; Pretty sure that's impossible since Pi shutdown wifi/router service before shutdown himself.
2. When Im at school, I have to connect my laptop with my Pi as ethernet so any of them has internet. I would like to connect my laptop to Pi as wifi (Pi as a router) and connect the pi to a wifi at the same time to get internet (atleast for the pi, I don't really need internet on my laptop).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

1. The LEDs on the board should tell you when its shut down. If not drill a hole in the case ;-)
2. The easiest way would be to let the PI connect to the school network in the same way your laptop does. If you do it for the first time you may need keyboard, mouse and monitore to do it, but then it can connect automatically.

The hard way would be to configure your laptop as a router for the PI. If you run Windows on your laptop then look up "internet connection sharing".

Comment: More specifically, the green ACT led on the Pi 3 will flash intermittently while shutting down the way it normally does when busy (this probably takes < 5 seconds), then blink in an even pulse @ ~2 Hz for a few seconds, then go out and stay out.  The red LED will remain on.  WRT wifi, the "hard way" may be the easy way if the school requires a web login, which is not unusual.

Comment: The led is visible but the red LED is always on and Im supposed to wait that yellow LED don't turn on anymore? You didn't understand my problem at school, I don't want connect to the school network, I have a friend who can set up a router on his phone to share the connection, I want to be able to connect my Pi on it to download packages or anything if needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. The raspberry pi website (sorry, can't find the link, I remember it though) says that after shutting down the pi, you should wait till the LEDs stop blinking, then wait another 10 seconds (to be safe), then you can turn the power off.